# Saving Plotly Pie Chart as Colored Image with PIL in Streamlit App

Tags: plotly, visualization, streamlit

I'm trying to create a Streamlit app that generates a pie chart from user-uploaded data and allows saving the chart as an image. While the chart displays colors correctly, the saved image using PIL appears in black and white.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import io

# ... your Streamlit app code with pie chart generation using px.pie ...

if submit_button:
    # ... your existing code ...

    img_bytes = fig.to_image(format='png')
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_bytes)).convert('RGB')
    img.save("demo.png")

    st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

Even though the code seems to be correct, the saved image is still black and white. What could be causing this issue?
Are there any additional steps I need to take to ensure the saved image retains color information from the Plotly pie chart?